# Explain a proof that there exists an increasing sequence $(a_n)_n$ of positive integers such that, for each $k\geq 1$, $(\arctan(ka_n))_n$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Show that there is an increasing sequence of positive integers $a_1<a_2<a_3<...$ such that for each $k\geq 1$, $\{\arctan(ka_n)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is convergent.

I have been given the answer as below:

> Note that when $k=1$, $\{\arctan(1\cdot n)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is bounded, so there is a subsequence $\{a_{1n}\}$ of $\{n\}$ such that $\{\arctan(1\cdot a_{1n})\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is convergent.
>
> Then, when $k=2$ there is a subsequence $\{a_{2n}\}$ of $\{a_{1n}\}$ such that $\{\arctan(2\cdot a_{2n})\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is convergent.
>
> Then use the diagonal method, and we let ${a_n}=a_{nn}$, and we done.

I think I understand that the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is increasing because $ ...\subset \{a_{2n}\} \subset \{a_{1n}\} \subset \{n\}$ , but why, for each $k$, this sequence made $\{\arctan(ka_{1n})\}_{n=1}^\infty$ convergent?

Please help to explain, thanks a lot!

Comment: "why this sequence made $\{\arctan(ka_{1n})\}_{n=1}^\infty$ convergent for each $k$?" It did not, rather, it is $\{\arctan(ka_{nn})\}_{n=1}^\infty$ which converges for each $k$.

Comment: $\{a_n\}\subseteq\cdots\subseteq\{n\}$??

Comment: $\arctan$ is increasing and has limit $\pi/2$. So $a_n = n$ suffices. No need to take subsequence at all...

Comment: Any increasing sequence of positive integers has this property; the limit is always $\pi/2.$

Comment: This is right. I added my answer below for explaining the original (indeed much more complicated) idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He finds out that the series $\{a_{1n}\}$ lets $\{\arctan(k \cdot a_{1n})\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converge for the case that $k=1$.

Then he finds out that the series $\{a_{2n}\}$ lets $\{\arctan(k \cdot a_{2n})\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converge for the case that $k\in \{1,2\}$.

And so he continues, so the series $\{a_{in}\}$ lets $\{\arctan(k \cdot a_{in})\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converge for the case that $k\in \{1,\ldots,i\}$ for every $i$.

But what he now needs is one series that works for every $k$. And the series $(a_n) := (a_{nn})$ does the job. Because let $k \in \mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary. Then we have by construction:

$\{ a_i : i \ge k\} = \{ a_{ii} : i \ge k\} \subset \{a_{kj} : j \in \mathbb{N} \}$

For proving the convergence, we can ignore the first $k-1$ elements of $(a_n)$, and for the others we know the convergence.